# add all data attr from element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to add all of the data attributes in an array

```
$('.lightbox-trigger').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
var image_src_arr = $('.lightbox-trigger').data('img-src');
console.log(image_src_arr);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7E5g/2/
but I get data attribute only the first element.
What's wrong? How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/), when you use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) as a getter then it will return the value from the first object in the calling set of objects

```
$('.lightbox-trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var image_src_arr = $('.lightbox-trigger').map(function () {
        return $(this).data('img-src');
    }).get()
    console.log(image_src_arr);

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kq4Bd/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this)` to target current clicked div with class `lightbox-trigger`:

```
var image_src_arr = $(this).data('img-src');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7E5g/3/)**

If you want to retrieve an array of `src` attribute then you can use `.map()`:

```
var image_src_arr = $('.lightbox-trigger').map(function () {
    return $(this).data('img-src');
}).get();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7E5g/4/)**